# Add text next to a Point in PCL visualizer

Tags: point-cloud-library

I have an application where I successfully plot 2D laser range data from a LiDAR in real-time and run PCL's Euclidean clustering algorithm to paint those cluster points in a different color. I would however like to add a text next to each detected cluster and tell its distance from the sensor. I do have the coordinate of the centroid point of each detected cluster but when I try to use the addText:

bool pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::**addText** (const std::string &    text, int xpos, int ypos,double r,double g,double b,const std::string & id = "")

text: Text to be printed in window

xpos: position in x

ypos: position in y

r: red

g: green

b: blue

id: Text ID tag

It seems like the function addText() puts the text in on PIXEL x- and y-values in stead of real-world values (meters). However, PCLs other method such as "addPoint()", addCircle() etc are indeed placing the data based on real world measurements.

**Does anyone have experience with transforming spatial coordinates to pixels in PCL visualizer, or have successfully plotted text in other ways?**

Below is a screenshot of my application. Clusters are drawn in red with a white circle around the centroid. At the bottom left I'm printing the distance of each cluster. As can be seen they are just stacked on top of each other instead of being added on top of its own white circle.

Thankful for any help

regards
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHwSm.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey I got it to work with a function called: pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::**addText3D**.

There is no support for erasing/updating all text fields that have been added over a period of time though, so one always needs to know the ID tags of each respective text and iterate through them to erase/update them.

You can delete texts with function: pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::**removeText3D**

Do however keep in mind that text ID tags share the same memory space as other ID name tags (e.g names you have given circles, clouds or cylinders etc). This means that if you try to add a text of name "abc" they command will fail if there is a circle pressent in your window named "abc".

Below is a visual example of how it looks now.[Obstacle distance plotting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoH0q.png)